# Typescript: How to infer the generic type a class from the function it's passed to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a few functions to retrieve some data from an API. They all take a filter object to filter the requests. The `Filter` class is generic, as I need to ensure that the user can only send defined properties to filter on.

```
export interface Item {
    name: string
    sku: string
}

export interface User {
    name: string
    email: string
}

export class Filter<T> {
    add(prop: keyof T, value: any) {
        // save property internally
    }
}

export function getItems(filter: Filter<Item>): Promise<Item[]> {
    // do work
}

export function getUsers(filter: Filter<User>): Promise<User[]> {
    // do work
}
```

The only problem with this is that the `filter` parameter for the get functions do not infer the generic argument for `Filter`. For example:

```
getItems(new Filter().add("foo", "bar")) // should error
getItems(new Filter<Item>().add("foo", "bar")) // does error
```

Is there a way to correctly infer the generic type argument for `Filter` when calling `getItems` & `getUsers`?

Comment: [**Works for me**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSVQFs4BvAKDiriUyOAC44BnGKZAc0uuYGsBXJq3ZIuAX3LlQkWIhRosuOAFVmaMtyq16Qtp01xgRTAgA2ukeMnTo8bKczNmcAGJnUUADwAVAHwbqOEwAE2CACjAoCDAmXmAATwh0OG8AGjgAN0xTfkYgpHiASiY3Uw8ffwpAqihgGH4oJDgYAAsEZgBuAwkJKXBbOHR+JGwYBAgmjjrCI2Yw9Hc0EsWvGaJfYrgABSiiduBPNYBtAF1K7lr6xu3d-YA6WuYIUwzgMNPCrt6bWSGRsYmcCmMFUaDmCzKS1cK08oKgGyYOwgezUsLUUFO5xqdQaTSRKOAD2ATxebw+X0kwLWcyQwAA7tDIVAwoU7iFwgAidAQCAc9IcgBGmCgHMKhTgAHoJYYoFEoOQqcQafTGeU1r4WWzQmEuTy+XBBcLReKpTK5QrpkqwrSGaU1cQNaz2TrtMB9RzmMbJdKwI5mEA).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. In your example, you have `getItems(new Filter().add("foo", "bar")) // error` on line 16. I would expect this to error, as "foo" is not a valid property of `Item`. If you change "foo" for "name", however, it still errors when it shouldn't.

Comment: I still don't get what you want then. And it has errors as you said because it assumes `never` when you don't pass the type to the class. If you pass `Item` as type it just works.

Comment: I want it to infer the type `Filter<Item>` from the fact the `getItems` function's signature specifies it. Yes, I could add in the generic type myself, but things start to get messy when the actual class names are imported from another module and are longer than `Item`. It just seems unnecessary to have to cast it twice. Typescript even errors with the following `getItems(new Filter<User>())`, so it's not like it doesn't understand what should be passed in

Comment: [**Check this**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSVQFs4BvAKDiriUyOAC44BnGKZAc0uuYGsBXJq3ZIuAX3LlQkWIhRosuOAFVmaMtyq16Qtp27AimBABtdIrlv5EmSawCM0AbnISp4aPGwnMzZnAAxU1QoAB4AFQA+DWo4TAATeNCAaThQVCR4-15gAE8IdDhwgBoVNJAMrKKAbWSAXUiACjAoCDAmZNKAN0wTfkYVAEomIJMQiOiKWKooYBh+KCQ4GAALBGYXWIk3aU84dH4kbBgECCWOOcJDZgnG9GC0EYewqOG4AAVWonXgCOqGmJwWbzRYfL4-AB0s2YEBMXWAjX+gxcbguMCuRGYjSQwAA7oFnqEMU1BhCEvFGgAiQzGEyU0qU5iUwbI8hojFYnH40bjYmNUnkqnaYD0uCM5ms9nETl4gljNChVRoElkxJUvj8UXilkuKXXbGynkKpVQFWCyl2Ihapk6tmXaUG7mEk1mtXUoyma0SlxAA).

Comment: That looks to solve a different issue and doesn't remove the need to pass in the generic argument. Cool functionality, but not the solution, unfortunately. Just to add a little bit, I'm most concerned with what the consumer code looks like (i.e. the call `getItems(new Filter())`) as I am developing a client library that exposes these methods and want it as non-verbose as possible

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that it isn't possible. Unless you have a default type for `T` (something like `export class Filter<T = Item>` - note that in this case, always you don't specify the type, `Item` will be assumed), you're obligated to pass the type `T` expected in `Filter`, otherwise it will be `never`.

Comment: That sucks, but isn't unexpected. Thanks for your help